# How to get next row in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

First I will select subject then subject will have Questions and options,
My Subject Controller

```
public function index()
{
    $subjects= Subject::all();
    return view('home',compact('subjects'));
}
```

My test Controller looks like this

```
public function startTest($id)
{
    $question =Question::where('subject_id','=',$id)->first();
    $nextquestion = Question::where('id','>',$question->id)->first();
    return view('user.Subject_and_question',compact('question','nextquestion'));
}
```

And my view looks like this,

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Question And answers
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td>
             <h4>{{$question->question}}</h4>
             @foreach($question->answers as $o)
                 <h5>{{$o->option1}}</h5>
                 <h5>{{$o->option2}} </h5>
                 <h5>{{$o->option3}}</h5>
                 <h5>{{$o->option4}}</h5>
         <td>
                  @if($nextquestion)
                     <a href="{{route('question.next_question', $nextquestion->id)}}" class="btn btn-success">Next Question</a>
                  @endif
         </td>
             @endforeach
         </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     </tr>
```

getting Trying to get property of non-object error,how can fix this.

Comment: Which line gives you that error?

Comment: In this line getting error, @if($nextquestion)
                     <a href="{{route('question.next_question', $nextquestion->id)}}" class="btn btn-success">Next Question</a>
                  @endif

Comment: Try `@if(isset($nextquestion))`.

Comment: still same error

Comment: Then use `dd($nextquestion)` to analyze the contents of that variable.

Comment: Yes i already did that its working, in view im getting an error,              
    "id" => 2
    "subject_id" => 1
    "question" => "father of java"
    "created_at" => "2017-05-03 14:08:50"
    "updated_at" => "2017-05-03 14:08:50"

Comment: With the code you've given and that debug output, I don't see how you could possibly be getting `Trying to get property of non-object error` on that line.

Comment: My questions table have id,sub_id,question.When i change subject_id in questions table im getting proper output,but its not correct question should come according to question id,

Comment: That's a totally different issue. Debug your query.